# fscanf is adding its variable onto another predefinied variable?

Tags: c, scanf

In the loop pasted below the variable `checker.idNumber` should just be a six digit number E.g. 326598. However when reading from the file I have the `fscanf` command adds the variable it just read and stored onto the `checker.idNumber` variable and I can't figure out why its doing that ?

```
   printf("Please input the student number of the record you wish to display: ");
   scanf("%6s", &checker.idNumber);
   fseek(pRead, 0, SEEK_SET);

do
{

  fscanf(pRead, "%6s", readLine);
  printf("%s\n", readLine);
  Sleep(2000);
  printf("%s\n", checker.idNumber);
  Sleep(2000);

}while(check != 0);
```

Comment: Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with *complete* code that demonstrates the problem. But my crystal ball tells me that your string arrays are not long enough. Don't forget the terminating `'/0'`.

Comment: Remember that C strings require a null terminator. If your buffer is exactly 6 characters, then you are overflowing the buffer by 1. And then when you read `apple`, it ovewrites the terminator.

Comment: You probably buffer overflow